# iOS 8.0 navigation error on button click navigation on cordova application

Tags: ios, iphone, knockout.js, cordova-plugins

I am using `cordova` application in my iOS. I integrated `peekaboo plugin` with my application successfully. I am using KnockoutJS.

When I click on a button to invoke the plugin which redirects current window to other window then it gives error on navigation. I tried many things like arbitrary loads flag to yes and also sub domain but all failed.

Here is the exception which is occurring.

```
2018-09-06 09:22:25.049995+0500 [3556:183610] ** WebKit discarded an 
uncaught exception in the 
webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: 
delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> ** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary 
initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from 
objects[2]
```

Can anyone give me a solution on this?